# Find iFrame in HTML and check its SRC

Tags: php, regex, iframe, html-parsing

I have a website where a user can **among other objects like text and images** also insert a YouTube video into CKEditor type textarea form.

YouTube video is embedded by iFrame objects.  But I don't want users to be able to insert any other iFrame except for YouTube (I am sure you can guess why)

So when the form is submitted I want to scan the **$text** variable for all iFrames and if they do not point to **youtube.com** or **youtube-nocookie.com**, remove those iFrame tags.

These are iFrames with allowed sources:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/6dk-5HN4fvg" width="640"></iframe>

<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/IY37l4PDsao" width="640"></iframe>
```

The task:

1. find the iFrame
2. find the value of its SRC
3. check if it is an allowed domain
4. if not delete it, or disable it, but preserve the rest of the surrounding HTML
5. check if there is another

Comment: Take a look at the [PHP DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). You should not parse HTML with regular expressions :).

Comment: Can we see what you have researched/tried so far? It's somewhat unusual to receive a question just stating requirements from a 11K user `:-)`.

Comment: Use jquery to find the frame via a ID (give an id to the frame), then use chrome developer tools to pause, and inspect the jquery frame and its proiperties.  Then find the src property, and set that via jquery as well, to another link.  You may have to force a refresh on the iframe, google will help you do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of utilizing **DOM** and XPath to achieve this task.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;

@$doc->loadHTML($html); 
$doc->removeChild($doc->doctype);

$xp  = new DOMXPath($doc);
$tag = $xp->query("//iframe[not(contains(@src, 'youtube.com') or 
                                contains(@src, 'youtube-nocookie.com'))]");

foreach ($tag as $t) {
   $t->parentNode->removeChild($t);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: That looks really good. Looking at the output, I would have to remove DOCTYPE Html and Body tags, as this is a content of an article, not the entire page. Is there are a way to omit these tags?

Comment: One more thing, in your example if you insert some other HTML code between, before or after the iFrame blocks will it be preserved? Will it preserve the rest of input?

Comment: You can set `$doc->preserveWhiteSpace` to true or false.

Comment: Thank you, works great. This is amazingly simple and easy to modify in the future.

Comment: One security improvement would be if instead of that SRC 'contains' there is a condition that it starts with "//www.youtube.com/". But cannot find the list of possible expressions.